# What is a Spaced Out Word™?

Tags: pattern, word-property

This is my first try at a puzzle, so hopefully it at least lasts a few hours before someone figures it out :)

<sub>This is in the spirit of the [What is a Word/Phrase™](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/search?q=%22what+is+a%22+word+is%3Aquestion) series started by [JLee](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/users/463) with a special brand of [Phrase™](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/search?q=%22Phrase%22%20user%3A463%20is%3Aquestion) and [Word™](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/search?q=%22What+is+%22+%22Word%22+-missing+user%3A463+is%3Aquestion) puzzles.</sub>

If a word conforms to a special rule, I call it a Spaced Out Word™.

Use the following examples below to find the rule.

[image]

And, if you want to analyze, here is a CSV version:

```
Spaced Out Words™,Not Spaced Out Words™
HUMILIATE,DEGRADE
HEXAGONALLY,OCTAGONALLY
DUNGEON,CATACOMB
NEFARIOUSLY,HEINOUSLY
NONSPHERICAL,NONCUBIC
WOOZINESS,DIZZINESS
PRECOGNITION,CLAIRVOYANCE
EXTENSION,ANNEX
```

**UPDATE:**

It occurred to me that, even if a puzzler were to reverse-engineer my criteria from the words above, they may not be able to fully determine the rules. To help, here are some additional words that are Not Spaced Out Words™ to narrow down the criteria:

> ```
>  CELEBRATION
>  WEATHERMEN
>  MANIPULATING
>  ADORINGLY
> ```

It's less of a hint and more of a clarification, but I put them in spoiler text for those who may want to solve the puzzle as it was originally written (and maybe refer back to these after, for verification).

**ADDITIONAL WORDS**

Below are a few more Spaced Out Words™ and Not Spaced Out Words™:

> ```
>  Spaced Out Words™,Not Spaced Out Words™
>  AROUSING,EXCITING
>  ADJOURN,RECESS
> ```

And a few more if you need more. I think this just about exhausts the list...

> ```
>  Spaced Out Words™,Not Spaced Out Words™
>  POVERTYSTRICKEN,IMPOVERISHED
>  UNCOPYRIGHTED,PUBLICDOMAIN
> ```
>
> (yes, that last Not Spaced Out Word™ is technically two words)

Comment: Welcome to Puzzling! c:

Comment: In the image it's Noncubic, and in the csv format it's noncubical - does this make odds as to whether this can be solved - if so which should be used?

Comment: Sorry; either works (noncubic and noncubical are both Not Spaced Out Words™), but I just didn't like the sound of "noncubical" while I was prepping the image and decided to change it... but didn't update the CSV >_<

Comment: are there any Extra Spaced Out Words™?

Comment: @Areeb added some more

Comment: This is intriguing. I'm interested to see what the result is. I'd say it's something to do with the fact that most of these do include extra words (Like precognition and cog) but it's not on every word, so who knows. I can't see a pattern. (I'm new to this, so that's probably normal haha) Good work with this, I assume it's good, it's intriguing me at least.

Comment: Maybe its spaced out... over the alphabet.

Comment: Okay, I'm thinking I cho*s*e too ambiguous of a term. The term I'd initially *c*ome up with was way too easy a g*i*veaway, but I think this choic*e* may have bee*n* too vague. Stare *c*losely at this comm*e*nt for an extra hint.

Comment: To avoid in others the eye strain I have just suffered: the hint is "science".

Comment: Aha. Here on PSE, "science" can only mean one thing: chemical symbols. `:)`

Comment: Your comment that the last hint `just about exhausts the list` is what triggered my answer. The idea that there could only be so many examples was not something that I had considered.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

The solution is that Spaced Out Words™ contain the letters for

> Homonuclear gases at room temperature.
>
>  `Word™           Element`
>  `----------------------------`
>  `HUMILIATE       HELIUM`
>  `HEXAGONALLY     OXYGEN`
>  `DUNGEON         NEON`
>  `NEFARIOUSLY     FLUORINE`
>  `NONSPHERICAL    CHLORINE`
>  `WOOZINESS       OZONE`.
>  `PRECOGNITION    NITROGEN`
>  `EXTENSION       XENON`
>  `AROUSING        ARGON`
>  `ADJOURN         RADON`
>  `POVERTYSTRICKEN KRYPTON`
>  `UNCOPYRIGHTED   HYDROGEN`

Comment: This is soooo close, like, invading its personal space close -- I'm looking for a specific term (one in which "wooziness" fits). Try the three letter word from within your answer on WP and see if you can find the term there that all twelve fit in. I suppose "unaccumulation" could be a Spaced Out Word™, but WP says relativistic effects might disqualify it (hence why it wasn't on my list).

Comment: Looking at my puzzle in retrospect, I think I need to choose the term more carefully; "Spaced Out" covers the broad criteria, but does nothing to help nail down the term I had in mind.

Comment: @DoktorJ So I think WP means Wikipedia and I [checked there](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gas) and poked in a few different places but nothing bit me. I checked [Litscape](http://www.litscape.com/word_tools_mammoth_uncensored/words_out_of_these_letters.php) for all the possible answers and, again, nothing leapt out at me. If my idea of how information is hidden - even if the list of *what* is hidden is incorrect - it should be in Litscape. Now I am re-frustrated... I have presumed that mechanical engineers have little use for chemistry knowledge. Lies!

Comment: You have the right words... and even the right Wikipedia page. The term is linked there.

Comment: Homonuclear gas molecules. (Personally I think Engineer Toast should have the checkmark already, but I'm guessing those are the words you want to see him write :-).)